# What do the numbers on the left side mean? Practical Reverse Engineering book

Tags: assembly

I tried searching, but I couldn't find anything that offered an explanation so this was my last resort. It's probably a dumb question, but what do the highlighted numbers on the left mean?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: May you please also check this doc link, and give me some feedback, if it was of some value, or just wasting time, and if you did understand it, or if you have some questions.... http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/assembly/1358/introduction-to-assembly/8901/machine-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the Intel machine codes representing the assembly code to the right. When your assembler (MASM, TASM, NASM, etc.) compiles your assembly code it emits the Intel machine code as it's output into an object file and/or executable.

Comment: Ah! That's a very neat process to see. Thank you!

Comment: If that answers your question please mark it as the solution. Thanks